# Wix Installer AllowDowngrades = No does not work

Tags: windows, wix, installation

I'm trying to implement version control with WIX installer so that installation of lower version is will be aborted

With this code, WIX detect newer version and uninstall older version as expected.

But when I try to install the older version over newer one, the installer still runs, creating an empty installation of our product ( Contains and modifies nothing but create one installation )

```
<Product Id="*" 
        Name="MyName" 
        Language="1033" 
        Version="!(bind.FileVersion.SomeDLL.dll)" 
        UpgradeCode="0ABC2FDA-9AA8-4418-934F-F99C3B205809">

            <Package InstallerVersion="400"
             Compressed="yes"
             InstallScope="perMachine"
             Manufacturer="!(loc.Manufacturer)"
             Description="!(loc.PackageDescription)"
             Comments="!(loc.PackageComments)"
             SummaryCodepage="!(loc.Codepage)" />

            <MajorUpgrade 
             AllowDowngrades="no"
             DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of !(loc.ProductName) is already installed." 
             AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no"
             Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"/>
</Product>
```

Here's a the image

[image]

i.stack.imgur.com/jJA0S.jpg

Can someone give me a pointer on what's happening here?

Comment: You should post the following information for the old and upgrade MSI setups: ProductCode, UpgradeCode. Assuming youi've got them correct, the likely explanation is that your InstallScopes are different: one is per user the other per machine, or vice versa.

Comment: Also report the ProductVersions, sorry.

Comment: @PhilDW : I've updated the relevant part of the code, I'm installing the application on the same PC with the same user

Comment: ProductVersions, ProductCode and UIpgradeCode are needed from both the old and the new installs, the actual values. Get them from eachg MSI file with Orca if necessar.y. It's not possible to see from the posted info why the upgrade may fail.

Comment: @PhilDW I specified that the product code is generated every time "*"

I have not specified a UIUpgradeCode

The version is customized as you can see in the image